# Limiting a mysql result

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a SQL statement to return the latest record for each subject for a person,

```
Database
Counter,Name,Subject,Grade
1,PersonA,Maths,C
2,PersonB,Maths,B
3,PersonA,English,B
4,PersonB,English,A
5,PersonA,Maths,A
6,PersonB,Maths,B
```

I would like to return that latest result for PersonA

```
5,PersonA,Maths,A
3,PersonA,English,B
```

How would this be achieved?

Comment: [What have you already tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: try this [link](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=22661).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select t1.Name,t1.Subject,t1.Grade
From SomeTableName t1
inner join (Select Name,Subject,Max(Counter) As Counter 
            From SomeTable 
            Group By Name,Subject) t2
On t1.counter = t2.counter
```

Comment: Hi Tony, Ta Very Much, You answer worked great and returned results very quickly. Going to do further reading on Uncorrelated subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Name='PersonA' ORDER BY Counter DESC LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: what if the 2 last counters are for the same subject ?

Comment: This won't work if the last two entries are both for Maths, for example. The English grade will not be returned at all.

Answer (score 0):

This also works if you can only use grouped columns in a result:

```
SELECT *
  FROM database
 WHERE counter IN(SELECT max(counter)
                    FROM database
                   GROUP BY subject)
  AND name 'PersonA'
```

Comment: You will also need to GROUP BY name: (GROUP BY name, subject). Tony Hopkinson's answer will work correctly.

Comment: For that to work, you'd have to put and name = 'PersonA' in the inner query as well....

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * from
(SELECT distinct columnA, columnB, MAX(counter) as id FROM table_name
group by columnA, columnB) as table1
inner join (select * from table_name) as table2 on table1.counter = table2.counter
```

Comment: distinct is unnecessary. Group by does that bit